# What spaces does a flyer threaten?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, opportunity-attack, flight

Would a small size character hovering above a foe spell caster threaten the square he is in and all squares he could reach with a 5 ft. Step?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Aerial combat in 3.5e](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/21569/aerial-combat-in-3-5e)

Comment: @thedarkwanderer: Meh, that's a little too "Read The Friendly Manual" to my mind.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Would a small size character hovering above a foe spell caster
>   threaten the square he is in and all squares he could reach with a 5
>   ft. Step?

Under DnD 3.5 rules combat is generally described in terms of a grid, 2D.  However, it is acknowledged within the rules that both swimming and flying make the 2D view of combat too limited.  See the section on Moving in Three Dimensions (DMG p20) for a little more on that.

In short, a hovering character (and hovering is key here), would offer threat in all three dimensions.  Movement rates AND maneuverability have to be kept in mind when flying, see table 2-1: Maneuverability (DMG p20).

Finally, flying/hovering folk can be threatened by opponents on the ground as well.  The rules work as written but everyone will have to think about more when the combat area is based on cubes rather than squares.